# Creating Floating Labels - Not Traversing the DOM Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I'm trying to creating a floating label that appears when you type into the input box. I think my problem is I am not correctly traversing the dom to hide the label, but I'm not sure.

Here is a link to the sample code: 
https://codepen.io/holly-williford/pen/GBVQqZ

Thanks,

Holly

```
<form>
<div>
    <label class="floating-label js-hide-label">Test</label> 
        <input placeholder="test" class="input" type="text"> 
    <label  class="floating-label js-hide-label">Test 2</label>
        <input placeholder="test1" class="input" type="text">
</div> 
</form> 



  $('form div').find('input').on('keyup', function(e)
{

    var $this = $(this),
        $sibling = $this.previousSibling();


    if (e.type == 'keyup') 
    {
        if($this.val() != '' ) 
        {
            $sibling.removeClass('js-hide-label');
        } 

        else 

        {

        }

}});

.js-hide-label {
opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good practice for accessibility to add `id`s to your `input`s and `for`s to your `label`s to associate the two together, updated example:

```js
$('form div input').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $label = $("label[for='"+$this.attr('id')+"']");
  if ($this.val() === '') {
    $label.addClass('js-hide-label');
  } else {
    $label.removeClass('js-hide-label');
  }
});
```

```css
.floating-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.js-hide-label {
  opacity: 0;
}

form {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div>
    <label for="test" class="floating-label js-hide-label">Test</label> 
  <input id="test" placeholder="test" class="input" type="text"> 
  <label for="test2" class="floating-label js-hide-label">Test 2</label>
  <input id="test2" placeholder="test1" class="input" type="text">
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful post. Always trying to learn best practices.

Answer (score 0):

To select the "immediately preceding sibling" use `$this.prev()` (see: https://api.jquery.com/prev/) not `$this.previousSibling()`. I changed that in your sample and it worked.

There is also the vanilla JavaScript way to get the previous sibling (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks! Ugh, I feel bad I missed that basic selector. *face palm* I swear I do research a lot before seeking outside help, but I just transitioned from mostly working with css & html to learning more javascript so having some hiccups. Thanks again!

Comment: @HollyWilliford no worries, glad we could help